# Spring-Boot application fails to find property factory_class for ehcache

Tags: spring, jpa, ehcache, spring-boot

I'm working on a spring application (using spring-boot) that worked well until this morning. I now need to configure a second datasource to use two different database (mysql + embedded h2).

I now have two classes "MainDatabaseConfiguration" and "EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration", which both provide a Bean of type "DataSource" (mainDataSource and embeddedDataSource), as well as associated Beans of type "EntityManager", "EntityManagerFactory" and "TransactionManager".

Unfortunately, The application initialization fails with the following error :

```
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:83)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:363)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
...
```

However, when i look in my config file :

```
application-dev.yml:
server:
    port: 8080
    address: localhost

spring:
    profiles: dev
    datasource:
        main:
            dataSourceClassName: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:jhipster
            databaseName: 
            serverName: 
            username: 
            password:
        embedded:
            dataSourceClassName: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:jhipster
            databaseName: 
            serverName: 
            username: 
            password:
    jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        database: H2
        openInView: false
        show_sql: true
        generate-ddl: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
        properties:
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

    thymeleaf:
        mode: XHTML
        cache: false

metrics:
    jmx.enabled: true
    graphite:
        enabled: false
        host:
        port:

cache:
    timeToLiveSeconds: 3600
    ehcache:
        maxBytesLocalHeap: 16M

# You can add as many as folders to watch
# You just need to add a dash + the directory to watch
hotReload:
    enabled: true
    package:
      project: com.sfr.sio
      domain: com.sfr.sio.domain
      restdto: com.sfr.sio.web.rest.dto
    liquibase:
      defaultCatalogName: 
      defaultSchema: public
    watchdir:
      - target/classes
```

The property "hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" is present. The only changed i made to that file for the second datasource is in the "spring.datasource" section to split it in two (spring.datasource.main and spring.datasource.embedded).
(Note : Both datasources are H2 in my dev environment, but mysql is used in production)
As you can see, the property mentionned in the error is present but spring seems to fail to retrieve it.

The code for the other classes that could be involved in the error :

mainDataSourceConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mainEntityManagerFactory", 
        transactionManagerRef = "mainTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "com.sfr.sio.repository" })
public class MainDatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractDatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

    /** prefix for the main datasource properties. **/
    private static final String MAIN_DATASOURCE_PREFIX = "spring.datasource.main.";

    /** Logger. */
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainDatabaseConfiguration.class);


    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, MAIN_DATASOURCE_PREFIX);
    }

    /**
     * Main Datasource bean creator.
     * <ul>
     * <li>Mysql for qualif and sfr environments</li>
     * <li>h2 for dev environment</li>
     * </ul>
     * 
     * @return the datasource.
     */
    @Bean(name="mainDataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        log.debug("Configuring Datasource");
        if (propertyResolver.getProperty(URL_PARAMETER) == null && propertyResolver.getProperty(DATABASE_NAME_PARAMETER) == null) {
            log.error("Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application" +
                    "cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
                    Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

            throw new ApplicationContextException("Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
        }
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName(propertyResolver.getProperty(DS_CLASS_NAME_PARAMETER));
        if (propertyResolver.getProperty(URL_PARAMETER) == null || "".equals(propertyResolver.getProperty(URL_PARAMETER))) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty(DATABASE_NAME_PARAMETER, propertyResolver.getProperty(DATABASE_NAME_PARAMETER));
            config.addDataSourceProperty(SERVER_NAME_PARAMETER, propertyResolver.getProperty(SERVER_NAME_PARAMETER));
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty(URL_PARAMETER, propertyResolver.getProperty(URL_PARAMETER));
        }
        config.addDataSourceProperty(USER_PARAM, propertyResolver.getProperty(USERNAME_PARAMETER));
        config.addDataSourceProperty(PASSWORD_PARAMETER, propertyResolver.getProperty(PASSWORD_PARAMETER));
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    /**
     * @return the entity manager for the main datasource
     * @see MainDatabaseConfiguration.dataSource()
     */
    @Bean(name = "mainEntityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * @return the entity manager factory for the main datasource
     * @see MainDatabaseConfiguration.dataSource()
     */
    @Bean(name = "mainEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.sfr.sio.domain");
        lef.setPersistenceUnitName("mainPersistenceUnit");
        lef.afterPropertiesSet();
        return lef.getObject();
    }

    /**
     * @return the transaction manager for the main datasource
     * @see MainDatabaseConfiguration.dataSource()
     */
    @Bean(name = "mainTransactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }

    /**
     * Liquibase bean creator.
     * @return the liquibase bean
     */
    @Bean
    @Profile(value = Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
        liquibase.setContexts("development, production");
        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

The only differences between MainDatabaseConfiguration and EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration are the replacement of mainDatasource by embeddedDatasource. the code is otherwise the same.

CacheConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = {MetricsConfiguration.class, MainDatabaseConfiguration.class, EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration.class})
public class CacheConfiguration {

    /** Logger. */
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheConfiguration.class);

    /** Entity manager. */
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="mainPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager mainEntityManager;

    /** Current environment. */
    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    /** Metrics regitry. */
    @Inject
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    /** Ehcache manager. */
    private net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager cacheManager;

    /** TTL parameter. */
    private static final Integer CACHE_TIME_TO_LIVE = 3600;

    /**
     * Prepare destroy of the object.
     */
    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        log.info("Remove Cache Manager metrics");
        SortedSet<String> names = metricRegistry.getNames();
        for (String name : names) {
            metricRegistry.remove(name);
        }
        log.info("Closing Cache Manager");
        cacheManager.shutdown();
    }

    /**
     * Cache manager bean creator.
     * @return the cache manager.
     */
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        log.debug("Starting Ehcache");
        cacheManager = net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create();
        cacheManager.getConfiguration().setMaxBytesLocalHeap(env.getProperty("cache.ehcache.maxBytesLocalHeap", String.class, "16M"));
        log.debug("Registring Ehcache Metrics gauges");
        Set<EntityType<?>> entities = mainEntityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities();
        for (EntityType<?> entity : entities) {

            String name = entity.getName();
            if ( name == null ) {
                name = entity.getJavaType().getName();
            }
            Assert.notNull(name, "entity cannot exist without a identifier");

            net.sf.ehcache.Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache(name);
            if (cache != null) {
                cache.getCacheConfiguration().setTimeToLiveSeconds(env.getProperty("cache.timeToLiveSeconds", Integer.class, CACHE_TIME_TO_LIVE));
                net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache decoratedCache = InstrumentedEhcache.instrument(metricRegistry, cache);
                cacheManager.replaceCacheWithDecoratedCache(cache, decoratedCache);
            }
        }
        EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager();
        ehCacheManager.setCacheManager(cacheManager);
        return ehCacheManager;
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long post. I hope it's clear enough. Don't hesitate to ask for precisions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After debugging it seems that the properties from application.properties file are picked up later during the initialization process and are not yet ready when the SessionFactory is being initialized.

The following may turn out as an ugly solution, but it worked for me:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    final LocalSessionFactoryBuilder localSessionFactoryBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    localSessionFactoryBuilder.scanPackages(myModelPackage);
    localSessionFactoryBuilder.setProperty(Environment.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
    return localSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

This part goes into your DB configuration path.
As you can see I force the cache region factory property to be what I need at the early stage of session factory creation.